# Track windows process exit codes

Tags: powershell, process, wmi, exit-code

On some of our Citrix Desktops we have a problem with randomly terminating (crashing?) applications. Event log doesn't reveal anything.

My Idea was to track the starting and stopping of processes and their exit/error codes for a while and try to find a pattern.

My approach is via Powershell:

```
function Enable-ProcessStopTrace {            
[CmdLetBinding()]            
param(            
)             
$Query = "Select * From __InstanceDeletionEvent within 2 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"            
$Identifier = "StopProcess"            
$ActionBlock = {            
 $e = $event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance            
 write-host ("Process {0} with PID {1} has stopped at {2}" -f $e.Name, $e.ProcessID, $event.TimeGenerated)      


 $fmt = 'ProcessStopped: (ID={0}, Parent={1}, Time={2}, Name="{3}", ExitCode={4})'            
 $msg = $fmt -f $e.ProcessId, $e.ParentProcessId, $event.TimeGenerated, $e.Name, $e.Exitcode

 write-host ($msg)            
}            
Register-WMIEvent -Query $Query -SourceIdentifier $Identifier -Action $ActionBlock            
}

Enable-ProcessStopTrace
```

(shamelessly copied from a blogpost and modified)

I get a nice output everytime a process terminates, but "exitcode" is allways empty.

Is that the right approach? Can I get exit codes or error codes this way?
Or do I have to go a totally different route?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get it to work is this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5b318b42-27c9-49d1-8c19-c5d7f0b9dbb2/getting-exit-code-from-startprocess?forum=winserverpowershell

```
PS C:\> $notepad = Start-Process notepad++ -Wait -PassThru
<close the application at this point>
PS C:\> $notepad.exitcode
PS C:\> 0
```

the script runs (waits) in the background until the application closes (either gracefully or not), you can then run $applicationname.exitxcode to get the exit code.

Comment: Hm, it looks like that only works if I start the application explicitly via PS. I am searching for a solution that tracks all applications. Especially the ones that are started automatically, like "explorer". But it's a start. I will test it. maybe it reveals something.